# Do elasticsearch work on excel binary workbook

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to perform indexing and searching on all product of microsoft office. i had find out that it is not working on excel binary book(.xlsb).

I had perform indexing successfully but it is not able to find words from it.

I had tried following steps:

```
         curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/test/attachment/_mapping" -d '{
           "attachment" : {
             "properties" : {
               "file" : {
                 "type" : "attachment",
                 "fields" : {
                   "title" : { "store" : "yes" },
                   "file" : { "term_vector":"with_positions_offsets", "store":"yes" }
                 }
               }
             }
           }
         }'

         coded=`cat test.xlsb | perl -MMIME::Base64 -ne 'print encode_base64($_)'`
         json="{\"file\":\"${coded}\"}"
         echo "$json" > json.file
         curl -X POST "localhost:9200/test/attachment/" -d @json.file

         curl "localhost:9200/_search?pretty=true" -d '{
           "fields" : ["title"],
           "query" : {
             "query_string" : {
               "query" : "sheet"
             }
           },
           "highlight" : {
             "fields" : {
               "file" : {}
             }
           }
          }'
```

Comment: Can you describe what you have done so far (curl recreation)?

Comment: very 1st allocated shrad 2nd created mapping 3rd conversion into base64 4th index the document curl -X POST "localhost:9200/test/attachment/" @jxlsb.file"  then tried to search in it but unable to get proper result

Comment: Can you please update your question and give also the query you sent?

Comment: What version of elasticsearch are you using? The attachment type is parsed using Apache Tika, to make sure its not a bug, [I'd suggest setting it up in your local environment](http://tika.apache.org/0.10/gettingstarted.html) and trying to parse your file to see if it can read the text in it first

Comment: I am using 0.90.1 Elasticsearch

Answer (score 1):

We just added streaming/read-only xlsb support in POI (coming in 3.15-beta3).  Once that is released, we'll upgrade Apache Tika (1.15?), and then once Elastic upgrades, you should be good to go.

A mere 4 years later!

Comment: Apache Tika 1.15 was recently released, and it can now handle XLSB.